# Good approach to access static variable in service component

Tags: java, spring, components

```
 public interface ABCHelper { 
      ...
      ...
    }

    @Service(ABCHelper.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class ABCHelperImpl implements ABCHelper {
      private static String DEMO = "demo";
      ...
      ...
    }


@Service(XYZ.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class XYZHelperImpl implements XYZHelper {
      @Reference private ABCHelper abcHelper;
      ...
      ...
    }
```

Now to get the value of DEMO variable in XYZHelper ,which of the following approach is good:

Approach 1: Making DEMO variable as public and then accessing it as below:

```
@Service(XYZ.class)
        @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
        public class XYZHelperImpl implements XYZHelper {
          @Reference private ABCHelper abcHelper;
          ...
          ...
          void f() {
           String s = ABCHelperImpl.DEMO ;
          }
    }
```

Approach 2: Defining the static method in ABCHelperImpl and then approaching it as below:

```
@Service(ABCHelper.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class ABCHelperImpl implements ABCHelper {
      private static String DEMO = "demo";
      ...
      ...
  public static String getDemo() {
     return DEMO; 
   }
 }

@Service(XYZ.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class XYZHelperImpl implements XYZHelper {
      @Reference private ABCHelper abcHelper;
      ...
      ...
      void f() {
       String s = ABCHelperImpl.getDemo() ;
      }
}
```

Approach 3:

```
public interface ABCHelper { 
      ...
      ...
      public String getDemo();
    }

    @Service(ABCHelper.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class ABCHelperImpl implements ABCHelper {
      private static String DEMO = "demo";
      ...
      ...
  public static String getDemo() {
     return DEMO; 
   }
 }

@Service(XYZ.class)
    @Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
    public class XYZHelperImpl implements XYZHelper {
      @Reference private ABCHelper abcHelper;
      ...
      ...
      void f() {
       String s = abcHelper.getDemo() ;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach will be to move this variable to some `Constants` class
do it `public` and use it everywhere you need.